# Windows 8.1 With bing activation

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-activation, bing

Yesterday i bought a acer switch 10 and i want to install a clean copy of windows 8.1 to it. There is a product key in the UEFI bios and windows should take the key from it but i tried to install Pro and Core editions of windows 8.1 and none of them are picking up the product key. It came with a Windows 8.1 with bing, is it the same as Windows 8.1 Core? So is there any way to install a clean windows? or i am stuck with the one acer gave me?

Comment: No; its not the same; you need to install windows 8 with bing or install a different version with your own key

Comment: Another thing worth noting is devices with lower amounts of storage have a different disk layout where parts of the OS are read only and stored in the restore folder. A clean install may end up being considerably bigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issue with my new Dell laptop which has "Windows 8.1 with Bing" installed on it.

This version of "Windows 8.1 with Bing" is different than the standard Windows 8.1 or Pro.  So your key will not work with either using those ISO images.  As far as I have discovered, Microsoft does not offer an ISO of "Windows for Bing" for direct download. So you are going to be forced to purchase the physical Windows OS recovery media directly from Acer.

Acer:
http://store.acer.com/store/aceramer/en_US/eRecovery

Dell: (for people with the same issue with a Dell computer)
https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/media

Comment: And yup, since Microsoft is either giving "Windows 8.1 with Bing" to PC OEM manufacturers for free or at a very minimal cost, Microsoft / OEM manufactures are definitely going to recuperate if you are going to ask for recover media. Lenovo in this case charges $69 for the recovery media DVD pack for their low end PCs (sub $300 segment) http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/ht035659#purchase

Comment: This has been resolved here: http://www.pcsteps.com/210-download-windows-8-1-isos-legally-free-microsoft/ *Apparently the **.ISO** file is out there, if you look hard enough.* Then you just need to install without it prompting you for a key (explained here: http://www.pcsteps.com/627-install-windows-8-1-without-product-key/).

Comment: david6, this article isn't talking about Windows with Bing at all. Windows with Bing does require a product key to install properly which usually built into the BIOS of the laptop and is detected automatically if you are re-installing the proper version of Windows.